# Magento ver. 1.9.1.0 : Sort Products by Quantity and Price descending

Tags: mysql, magento

**I need to sort products by quantity and price** i.e. all the products of category should be listed by maximum quantity. Maximum quantity of product should come first then lower quantity products should be listed. I have achieved this by writing this code in 
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php

```
public function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
{
    if ($attribute == 'position') {
   /**** Sorting for quantity starts***************/         
        //join the stock status index table for the current website and check if the product is saleable and the qtu.
        $select = $this->getSelect();
        $select->joinLeft(
            array('stock_qty' => $this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')),
            'e.entity_id = stock_qty.product_id AND stock_qty.website_id='.Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(),
            array(
                'salable' => 'stock_qty.stock_status',
                'qty' => 'stock_qty.qty'
            )
        );
        //get the reversed sorting
        //if by position ascending, then you need to sort by qty descending and the other way around
        $reverseDir = ($dir == 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
        //this is optional - it shows the in stock products above the out of stock ones independent if sorting by position ascending or descending
        $this->getSelect()->order('salable DESC');
        //sort by qty
        $this->getSelect()->order('qty '.$reverseDir);
        return $this;      

/**** Sorting for quantity ends ***************/  

    } elseif($attribute == 'is_saleable'){
        $this->getSelect()->order("is_saleable " . $dir);
        return $this;
    }

    $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
    if ($attribute == 'price' && $storeId != 0) {
        $this->addPriceData();
        $this->getSelect()->order("price_index.min_price {$dir}");

        return $this;
    }

    if ($this->isEnabledFlat()) {
        $column = $this->getEntity()->getAttributeSortColumn($attribute);

        if ($column) {
            $this->getSelect()->order("e.{$column} {$dir}");
        }
        else if (isset($this->_joinFields[$attribute])) {
            $this->getSelect()->order($this->_getAttributeFieldName($attribute) . ' ' . $dir);
        }

        return $this;
    } else {
        $attrInstance = $this->getEntity()->getAttribute($attribute);
        if ($attrInstance && $attrInstance->usesSource()) {
            $attrInstance->getSource()
                ->addValueSortToCollection($this, $dir);
            return $this;
        }
    }

    return parent::addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
}
```

Now I need to sort products by price descending also i.e. quantity descending with price descending

```
Product  Quantity Price
-------  -------- -------
  A         100   9000
  B         100   8000
  C         89    7000
  D         80    6000
```

I also tried by going to **System > Configuration >  Catalog > Product Listing Sort by = Price** . But this does not help me. So I am looking for the solution, and I think the solution is by manipulating the code here

```
$select = $this->getSelect();
        $select->joinLeft(
            array('stock_qty' => $this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')),
            'e.entity_id = stock_qty.product_id AND stock_qty.website_id='.Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(),
            array(
                'salable' => 'stock_qty.stock_status',
                'qty' => 'stock_qty.qty'
            )
        );
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution: Add this line of code after sorting quantity by descending order ==>
         **$this->getSelect()->order('price DESC');**

```
$select = $this->getSelect();
        $select->joinLeft(
            array('stock_qty' => $this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')),
            'e.entity_id = stock_qty.product_id AND stock_qty.website_id='.Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(),
            array(
                'salable' => 'stock_qty.stock_status',
                'qty' => 'stock_qty.qty'
            )
        );
        //get the reversed sorting
        //if by position ascending, then you need to sort by qty descending and the other way around
        $reverseDir = ($dir == 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
        //this is optional - it shows the in stock products above the out of stock ones independent if sorting by position ascending or descending
        $this->getSelect()->order('salable DESC');

        //sort by qty
        $this->getSelect()->order('qty '.$reverseDir);
        $this->getSelect()->order('price DESC');
        return $this;
```